# JSOUP Scrape only subpages / no external links

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have the following code and I'm trying to scrape a website - but only the subpages (or relative links). I do not wish to scrape links which lead to external websites. I'm using Java and jsoup.

```
public void scrape(String url) {

    String docUrl = url;

    try {

        Document document = Jsoup.connect(docUrl).get();
        Elements foundUrls = document.select("a[href]");

        System.out.printf("Found %d links. %n", foundUrls.size());

        for (Element  foundUrl : foundUrls) {


            String nextUrl = foundUrl.attr("href");

            if (visitedLinks.contains(nextUrl)) {
                System.out.println("Link already visited. Skipping URL.");
            }

            else {

                System.out.println("Scraping: "+ nextUrl);
                visitedLinks.add(nextUrl);
                scrape(nextUrl);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.out.printf("Could not read %s.%n", url);
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how to scrape only the subpages of a page - so no external links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the code such that the check is not just to see if the link has been visited before scraping but also if the link is an in-site link. So the `if` statement should be changed to:

```
if (visitedLinks.contains(nextUrl) || !isInSiteLink(nextUrl) {
    // don't scrape
} else {
    // your scraping method here
}
```

Then you have to implement the method. It could look something like

```
boolean isInSiteLink(String url) {
    return (url.starts with(baseUrl) || url.startsWith("/") || url.starts with("./") || url.starts with("../"));
}
```

Where `baseUrl` is the base URL of the site.